# Excel conditional formatting to compare cell values within a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a data table with chronological weeks on the x axis and failure rates for different defect types on the Y axis.  I want to highlight all cells where the rate is say .005% higher than its previous week. In excel terms: if B2 >= A2 +.00005, highlight B2. If C2 >= B2 + .00005, highlight C2, and so on.

I selected the table went to "conditional formatting > new rule > use formula" and tried =B2>=A2+0.00005 but it's working on some cells, missing some cells and giving false positives on other cells. Looking at the first row for example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyWhR.png), you can see the left-most cell is formatted when it shouldn't be, the right-most cell is *not* formatted when it should be, and the middle ones are all correctly formatted. Other rows are similarly mixed up.

Any idea why my formula isn't working, and what I need to correct to get the desired output? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a formula for this conditional formatting.
Instead, use the rule type `Format only cells that contain` and set it to:
`Cell Value` `greater than or equal to` `=A2+0.00005`

Key Point: `A2` needs to be the right cell reference for the top left cell in your selection. In the example below, that's `B2`. Since this is a relative reference (as opposed to `$A$2`), it will update as needed for every other cell in the selected range.

[image: Screenshot]